# SelectList cached by AJAX

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vb.net, drop-down-menu

I have a DropDownList in MVC which grabs a SelectList initialized and populated by a controller. The goal of the specific page that said list resides on is to reply "You have selected option X" immediately to the user without refreshing (using Ajax).

The problem I'm running into is that for some odd reason, while the dropdown renders properly and even posts back correctly, any attempts to add new options or modify previous response messages are in vain.

My View:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../Scripts/MicrosoftAjax.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../../Scripts/MicrosoftMvcAjax.js"></script>
    <h2>Configuration</h2>
      <%  Using (Ajax.BeginForm("HandleConfigForm", New AjaxOptions With {.UpdateTargetId = "ConfigResults"}))%>
         Select the config file you wish to view: <%= Html.DropDownList("cprotocols")%>
         <br /><br />
       <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
       <br />
       <br />
       <span id="ConfigResults"></span>
       <% End Using%>
```

My Controller:

```
Function Configuration() As ActionResult

        Dim configList As List(Of String) = New List(Of String)
        configList.Add("A")
        configList.Add("B")
        configList.Add("C")
        configList.Add("D")
        configList.Add("test")

        ViewData("cprotocols") = New SelectList(configList)

        Return View()
    End Function

    Function HandleConfigForm(ByVal cprotocols As String) As String
        Select Case cprotocols
            Case "A"
                Return "You picked: dat option"
            Case "B"
                Return "You picked: dat option B"
            Case "C"
                Return "You picked: wat even is C"
            Case "D"
                Return "You picked: choice D"
            Case "test"
                Return "cache"
        End Select

        Return [String].Empty
    End Function
```

Previously my code did not have `"test"` (in neither `Configuration()` nor `HandleConfigForm())`; also, in Case "A" the comment used to say `"dat option A"`.

When I load my site, the dropdownlist shows options A through D, but no test... selecting a letter gives the appropriate message except A posts back `"dat option A"` rather than the new `"dat option"`.

I have absolutely no clue what's happening other than that somehow my function has broken and the browser is caching previous data that was loaded by Javascript. I have made no other changes to my code aside from simply adding to configList and changing the returns in the Select switch, so I don't see what could be going wrong.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The browser will cache the results of an ajax call just like it will cache the results of any other request.

One solution is to add an explicit OutputCache directive to your method with duration set to 0.

The method jQuery uses is to append a random querystring param to the url.

I've never used the MicrosoftAjax stuff, so I'm not totally sure how it works.